# MySQL: How to perfom a multiple-table query including a calculated sum?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, inner-join

Firstly, the relationships between the tables in question:[image]

I'm attempting to write a query which retrieves: people_has_trips.people_personID, people_has_trips_tripID, seminarname, agent, and "Amount," which is intended to be the total of all entries in the Payments table for a given entry in the Trip table. This is relevant because this query is meant to be used in a subform on the Access frontend I'm building. In simple terms, the concept for this query is: Which trip(s) has this person been on, and how much money was spent, total, on each trip?

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT 
    people_has_trips.people_PersonID,
    people_has_trips.trips_tripID,
    people_has_trips.seminar_seminarID,
    seminar.seminarname,
    agentref.agent,
    payments.amount
FROM
    (seminar
    INNER JOIN (((trips
    INNER JOIN people_has_trips ON trips.tripID = people_has_trips.Trips_tripID)
    INNER JOIN payments ON trips.tripID = payments.trips_tripID)
    INNER JOIN agentnotes ON trips.tripID = agentnotes.Trips_tripID) ON seminar.seminarid = people_has_trips.seminar_seminarid)
        INNER JOIN
    agentref ON trips.agentref_agentid = agentref.agentid;
```

Which returns the following:
[image: Query Result]

So we're most of the way there, obviously the final version will be cleaned up a bit (seminarID is unneccesary, for example), so my only question is: what do I need to do so that instead of "amount" showing every individual payment, it's a total of all payments for a trip?

Bonus: The keen-eyed will notice that "seminar" is actually a optional foreign key, and therefore this query, being made of inner joins, excludes any combination of people and trips which does not include a seminar. This is not intended, and another problem I'll need to solve.

Comment: It's not necessary to put parenthese around each join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for rearranging the SQL, but I had a hard time following what was going on until I reorganised it.

If you `GROUP BY` the columns other than the payment value you can use aggregate functions like `SUM` to get the total of the payments.

```sql
SELECT 
    people_has_trips.people_PersonID,
    people_has_trips.trips_tripID,
    people_has_trips.seminar_seminarID,
    seminar.seminarname,
    agentref.agent,
    SUM(payments.amount)
FROM seminar
INNER JOIN people_has_trips
    ON
    people_has_trips.seminar_seminarid = seminar.seminarid
INNER JOIN trips
    ON
    people_has_trips.Trips_tripID = trips.tripID
INNER JOIN payments
    ON
    trips.tripID = payments.trips_tripID
INNER JOIN agentnotes
    ON
    agentnotes.Trips_tripID = trips.tripID
INNER JOIN agentref
    ON
    agentref.agentid = trips.agentref_agentid
GROUP BY
    people_has_trips.trips_tripID,
    people_has_trips.people_PersonID,
    people_has_trips.seminar_seminarID,
    seminar.seminarname,
    agentref.agent
;
```

Comment: Perfect! This also made it clear to me that it actually doesn't make sense to include Seminar in the query, thank you!